# PyQt: translating standard buttons

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, translation, button

How can I easily translate standard buttons (Yes, No) from QMessageBox? I can't use self.tr on those arguments, so I would like to achieve it in some other simple way. Do I have to use whole translation system?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is how I did :

First you need to copy the `qt_LOCALE.qm` file to your application directory. Mine was :

```
cp /usr/share/qt4/translations/qt_fr.qm .
```

Secondly, you need to load a translator for your application.

```
application = QApplication(argv)

locale = QLocale.system().name()
qtTranslator = QTranslator()
if qtTranslator.load("qt_"+locale):
    application.installTranslator(qtTranslator)

main_window = QMainWindow()
main_window.show()

exit(application.exec_())
```

Answer (score 5):

The quickest way is something like this:

```
mymessagebox.button(mymessagebox.Yes).setText("Yes, please!")
mymessagebox.button(mymessagebox.No).setText("No, thanks.")
```

See the QMessageBox documentation for all possible [standard buttons](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qmessagebox.html#StandardButton-enum).

Comment: OK, this isn't really what I need - I am using question method and I can't really access QMessageBox instance to set this text. Can I achieve this in some other way?

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure you have to translate them yourself? In other toolkits, standard buttons are automatically translated to the language that the user is using.

Comment: No, I would prefer to have them translated automatically. But I have no idea how to achieve this.

Comment: What OS are you using? Have you tried logging in using a different language?

Comment: Ubuntu 9.10 I have everything in polish.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have Yes/No translated into the current language, usually setting the system language should be enough. Otherwise try with Natim's suggestion.

If you want custom texts: The static methods like question() etc. don't allow custom button texts. That's unfortunate, as "Yes"/"No" dialogs are considered bad style (they are not descriptive, one has to read the whole message, and its easy to misunderstand what means Yes and what means No and accidentally negating them). For custom texts, you have to use QMessageBox directly. I'd suggest to write your own static methods accepting optional button texts.