# PyQt: How can I change the texts of my QInputDialog buttons?

Tags: python, button, dialog, pyqt

I want to change the text for the buttons (OK, Cancel) in my `QInputDialog` box. 
 How can I achieve this?

I want to use Python's gettext to do the translations, not Qt Linguist.

```
# Set maximum file size
def maximumFilesize(self):

    # Get user input
    maxsize, ok = QtGui.QInputDialog.getInt(self, "Maximum file size",
        "Enter maximum file size in bytes:", self.maxsize, 1, 1073741824)

    # If OK was clicked...
    if ok:
        if maxsize <= 0:
            message = "Maximum file size cannot be less than 1."
                QtGui.QMessageBox.critical(self, "Error", message)
                return False

        # Set new maximum file size
        self.maxsize = maxsize
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `QInputDialog` itself contains methods `setOkButtonText` and `setCancelButtonText`, however, the static method `gitInt` you are using creates a `QInputDialog` object, which is visible only inside the `getInt` method and is not accessible to you.

I would suggest to create your own `InputIntegerDialog(QtGui.QInputDialog)`, on which you'll have to manually add a spinBox and set its properties. You would then be able to change text on both buttons, because the dialog object is under your control, not created somewhere inside PyQt.

BTW, if you only wish to translate standard buttons, you may want to see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1709528/pyqt-translating-standard-buttons).

Comment: I think I will learn the PyQt's translation system. But thank you for your answer =)