# Python script for Pymol with user input

Tags: set, user-input, python-3.7, pymol

I have prepared a script for Pymol that works well in evaluating RMSD values for a list of residues of proteins of interest (targetted residues are generated by script embedded commands). However, I wished to implement the script to allow the user to select the analysed residues. I have tried to use the input function, but it fails to work. Since the code is a bit long, I simplified progressively the scripts. In that way, I ended up with the following two scripts:

"test.py":

```
import Bio.PDB
import numpy as np
from pymol import cmd
import os,glob
from LFGA_functions import user_entered

List_tot = user_entered()
print (List_tot)
```

which calls the simple "user_entered" function from inside the "My_function.py" script:

```
def user_entered():
    List_res = []
    List_tot = []
    a = input("Please indicate the number of residues to analyze/per monomer:")
    numberRes =int(a)
    for i in range(numberRes):
        Res = input("Please provide each residue NUMBER and hit ENTER:")
        Res1 = int(Res)
        Res2 = Res1+2000
        Res3 = Res1+3000
        Res4 = Res1+4000
        Res5 = Res1+5000
        Res6 = Res1+6000
        List_res = (str(Res1),str(Res2),str(Res3),str(Res4),str(Res5),str(Res6))
        List_tot.append(List_res)
    return List_tot
```

The script "test.py" works well when executed by Python (3.7.5, which is installed with Pymol 2.3.4,under Windows 7 Prof) from a windows command line. An example of result:
[first input to indicate that 2 cases will be treated, followed by the identification number for each case][1]

However, when the script is run from Pymol GUI, I get the following error message: input():lost sys.stdin

Does anybody know what is the problem. Obviously, I am a very primitive Python user...

I profit also to ask something related to this problem... in the original script that works well in Pymol, before trying to implement the "input" option, I store transiently some data (residue name, type and chain) in the form of a "set". I need a set, and not a list, because it removes automatically data repeatitions. However, when I try to run it from PYthon (thinking of overcoming the abovementioned problem of input), it stops with a message: name 'close_to_A' not defined. However, it is as shown in the portion of code shown here below, and indeed works in Pymol.

```
...
# Step 3: 
# listing of residues sufficiently close to chainA
# that will be considered in calculation of RMSD during trajectory

cmd.load("%s/%s" %(path3,"Average.pdb"), "Average", quiet=0)
cmd.select("around_A", "Average and chain B+C near_to 5 of chain A")
cmd.select("in_A", "Average and chain A near_to 5 of chain B+C")
close_to_A = set()
cmd.iterate("(around_A)","close_to_A.add((chain,resi,resn))")
cmd.iterate("(in_A)","close_to_A.add((chain,resi,resn))")
cmd.delete("around_A")
cmd.delete("in_A")
...
```

How shall I define a set in Python 3 ? Why does it work when run from Pymol ?

I would really appreciate if you could help me to solve these two problems. Thank you in advance,

Best regards,

Luis

Comment: A bit more complicated but more reliable would be to use the approach described here: https://pymolwiki.org/index.php/Plugins_Tutorial

Comment: see here: https://pymolwiki.org/index.php/Launching_From_a_Script   PyMOL captures sys.stdout and sys.stderr, to control it with it's own feedback mechanism. To prevent that, save and restore both streams, e.g.: ù

Answer (score 0):

I tried to get user input in a pymol script (`cmd.run(script.py)` or from FileMenu/Run script ...) , I dont get your error but input from console get mixed up with pymol stdout. As suggested by M.Peters, I went for the plugin approach. My attempt below:

```
'''
PyMOL .............................. Plugin

'''


"""
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15849567/pyqt-how-can-i-change-the-texts-of-my-qinputdialog-buttons

The QInputDialog itself contains methods setOkButtonText and setCancelButtonText, however, the static method gitInt you are 
using creates a QInputDialog object, which is visible only inside the getInt method and is not accessible to you.

I would suggest to create your own InputIntegerDialog(QtGui.QInputDialog), on which you'll have to manually add a s
pinBox and set its properties. You would then be able to change text on both buttons, because the dialog object is 
under your control, not created somewhere inside PyQt.

"""


from pymol.Qt import QtWidgets , QtGui

def __init_plugin__(app=None):
    '''
    Add an entry to the PyMOL "Plugin" menu
    '''
    from pymol.plugins import addmenuitemqt
    
    addmenuitemqt('Plug', run_plugin_gui)

#### ATTENZIONE A GLOBAL DIALOG SUPER NECESSARIO ############
# global reference to avoid garbage collection of our dialog
dialog = None


def run_plugin_gui():
    '''
    Open our custom dialog
    '''
    
    global dialog

    if dialog is None:
        dialog = make_dialog()

    dialog.show()
    


 
class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)
        
        self.setGeometry(100,100,400,400)
           
        self.Winlayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        
        self.setLayout(self.Winlayout)
        
        self.button_start = QtWidgets.QPushButton('START')
        
        self.button_print = QtWidgets.QPushButton('PRINT')
        
        self.Winlayout.addWidget(self.button_start)
        
        self.Winlayout.addWidget(self.button_print)
    
        self.button_start.clicked.connect(self.inputz)
        
        self.button_print.clicked.connect(self.printz)
        
        self.List_tot = []
        
        self.List_res = []
        
        self.flag = {}
        
        
    def closeEvent(self, event):
        
        print('cloooooooooooooose') 
        
        event.accept()

        
    def inputz(self):
        
        self.flag['close'] = False
        
        while self.flag['close'] == False :
            
            self.showmydialog()

    def printz(self):
        
        print('\n\n-----------------------------------------------')
        
        print(self.List_res)
        
        self.List_tot = []
        
        for i in range(len(self.List_res)):
            
            Res1 = self.List_res[i]
            Res2 = Res1+2000
            Res3 = Res1+3000
            Res4 = Res1+4000
            Res5 = Res1+5000
            Res6 = Res1+6000
            
            List_app = (str(Res1),str(Res2),str(Res3),str(Res4),str(Res5),str(Res6))
        
            self.List_tot.append(List_app)
            
        print('\n', self.List_tot)
        
    def showmydialog(self):
        dialog = QtWidgets.QInputDialog(self)
        
        dialog.setInputMode(QtWidgets.QInputDialog.IntInput)
        
        dialog.setIntMaximum(2147483647)

        
        dialog.setWindowTitle("INPUT")
        dialog.setLabelText('Please indicate the '+(str(len(self.List_res)+1))+' residues numbers :')
        dialog.setOkButtonText("OK")                         
        dialog.setCancelButtonText("CLOSE")                   #
        if dialog.exec_() == QtWidgets.QDialog.Accepted:
            
            inpt = dialog.intValue()
            
            self.List_res.append(inpt)
            
        else:
            
            print('input finished , lenght List = ', (len(self.List_res)))
            
            self.flag['close'] = True
        
def make_dialog():

    dialog = Window()
    
    return dialog
```

I does not requst the user for the number  of residues

> Please indicate the number of residues to analyze/per monomer ,

but just let the user input as many numbers as he wish, until he hits the `CLOSE` button, you get a list as result. Using just `QInputDialog.getInt` would save a lot of lines but You'll end up with a `CANCEL` button instead of `CLOSE` that could be misleading (see notes at the beginning os code).

See https://pymolwiki.org/index.php/Plugins about how to install plugins.

[image]

**START** open the input widget, **PRINT** prints your iput derived list*

*list doesnt get reset between multiple **START** runs.

[[image]

Pressing **OK** stores the value in the list, **CLOSE** ends the input session

---

As for the second question , not sure I got it right , but try:

```
from pymol import(
                  cmd
                  stored
                  )

stored.close_to_A = set()
```

See https://pymolwiki.org/index.php/Pymol.stored

> The pymol.stored helper variable serves as a namespace for user defined globals which are accessible from iterate-like commands. The iterate commands by default expose the pymol module namespace as the globals dictionary, so pymol.stored is accessible as stored, and (user defined) members as stored.membername.

**EDITED**

As a second approach using pymol plugin, I tried to make a window that captures the selection available and enabled in "pymol name menu/object control panel" and prints the list of the corresponding residues, here how it looks like:

[image]

Here the code for it (save and enable/load as plugin):

```
from pymol import cmd, stored

from pymol.Qt import QtWidgets, QtCore



cmd.feedback('disable' , 'all', 'blather')



def __init_plugin__(app=None):
    '''
    Add an entry to the PyMOL "Plugin" menu
    '''
    from pymol.plugins import addmenuitemqt
    
    addmenuitemqt('Plug_3_61145572', run_plugin_gui)

#### ATTENZIONE A GLOBAL DIALOG SUPER NECESSARIO ############
# global reference to avoid garbage collection of our dialog
dialog = None


def run_plugin_gui():
    '''
    Open our custom dialog
    '''
    
    global dialog

    if dialog is None:
        dialog = make_dialog()

    dialog.show()
    
class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)
        
        self.selected = []
        
        self.List_tot = []
        
        self.setGeometry(300,300,400,400)
        
        self.setWindowTitle('Print Modified List of Residues')
    
        self.Winlayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        
        self.setLayout(self.Winlayout)
        

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        
        self.Winlayout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("background-color: #000;color:white; margin:5px")
        self.label.setText("PyMOL Plugin\n"
                           "\"Selection_Derived_List\"")
        self.label.setTextFormat(QtCore.Qt.PlainText)
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label.setWordWrap(True)
        
        
        self.display = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        
        self.display.resize(50,100)
        
        self.display.setStyleSheet( """ 
                                     QLabel {margin:5px; 
                                             border:5px solid blue;
                                             } """ )
                                     
        self.display.setTextFormat(QtCore.Qt.PlainText)
        self.display.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.display.setWordWrap(True)
        

        self.Winlayout.addWidget(self.display)
        
        self.button_print = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Print Modified List of Residues')
        
        self.Winlayout.addWidget(self.button_print)
        
        
        self.button_print.setEnabled(False)
        
        self.button_print.clicked.connect(self.print_list)

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        
        print('closing...................................')
    
    
    def enterEvent(self, event):
        print('Entering ..............................................................................................')
        
        self.set_sel_available()
        
        print('Exiting ................................................................................................')
  
        
    def set_sel_available(self):
        
        while  len(self.selected) > 0:   
            
            self.selected.pop()
        
        text = str()
        
        for i in cmd.get_names(type = 'selections', enabled_only = 1):
            
            text += i+'\n'
            
            self.selected.append(i)

        self.display.setText(text)

        print('selections  : ', text)
        
        if text != "":
            
            self.button_print.setEnabled(True)
            
        else:
            
            self.button_print.setEnabled(False)
            

    def print_list(self) :
        
        self.List_tot = []
        
        print('\n\n-----------------------------------------------')
        
        print(self.selected)
        
        stored.lista = []
        
        for i in self.selected:
        
            cmd.iterate(i , "stored.lista.append(resi)")
        
        list_resi = sorted(set(stored.lista))
        
        print('\n\n----------------------------------\n', list_resi)
        
        for i in range(len(list_resi)):
            
            Res1 = int(list_resi[i])
            Res2 = Res1+2000
            Res3 = Res1+3000
            Res4 = Res1+4000
            Res5 = Res1+5000
            Res6 = Res1+6000
            
            List_app = (str(Res1),str(Res2),str(Res3),str(Res4),str(Res5),str(Res6))
        
            self.List_tot.append(List_app)
            
        print('\n', self.List_tot)
        

def make_dialog():

    dialog = Window()
    
    return dialog
```